# Converting 'MM.YYYY' to a SAS date format like mmyy10

Tags: sas

I have a character string `'MM.YYYY'` and want to convert this to a date format in SAS - something like `format mmyy10.`. I know that since I am missing the day I can't use any `SAS day format`.

Right now I am solving this problem like:

```
data testdate;

chardate = '06.2010';
ch_month = int(chardate);
ch_year = (chardate-ch_month)*10000;
date = mdy(ch_month,15,ch_year);
format date mmyy10.;

run;
proc print data=testdate;
run;
```

I have one problem - the year will be **one year less** than what I expect. So my output is `06M2009`?! I get no errors whatsoever. What is wrong with this code? Another thing - is there (I bet there is) a better/nicer way to approach this problem?

**EDIT:** Fixed an error in the MWE, thanks to @Reeza

Comment: Your code has an error.

Comment: Thx @Reeza, I just restarted the EG and get one now too - gonna fix it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the INPUT() function.  Add a day of the month so you have a valid date value to input.

```
date = input('01.'||chardate,ddmmyy10.);
```

Your original calculations are using implicit type conversion and not accounting for the use of floating point arithmetic.  Add the BEST32. format to see your actual values.

```
data testdate;
  chardate = '06.2010';
  ch_month = int(chardate);
  ch_year = (chardate-ch_month)*10000;
  date = mdy(ch_month,15,ch_year);
  format _numeric_ best32. date yymmdd10.;
  put (_all_) (=);
run;

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
      108:17   109:18
chardate=06.2010 ch_month=6 ch_year=2009.99999999999 date=2009-06-15
NOTE: The data set WORK.TESTDATE has 1 observations and 5 variables.
```

Try adding a ROUND() function call

```
date = mdy(ch_month,15,round(ch_year,1));
```

Comment: Thx Tom, much appreciated! I already asked Reeza but do you have any idea why the year would be off by one? I can't figure it out...this is so weird.

Comment: Rounding error.  Your YEAR variable is really slightly less than 2010 and the MDY function truncates the value to just take the integer part.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways to convert it to a SAS date. A SAS date must have a 'day' component, even if not shown. I've set it to 1 here.

INPUT() converts character to numeric to avoid conversion notes in the log
SUBSTR() gets the month/year from the character string.

```
date = mdy(input(substr(chardate, 2, 2), 8.), 1, input(substr(chardate, 4, 4), 8.));
```

Or another approach is to use INPUT directly. 
First remove the period with the COMPRESS() function and then concatenate a 01 to the start of the date and read it as a DDMMYY formated date.

```
date2 = input(compress('01'||chardate, "."), ddmmyy10.);
```

Full code is here:

```
data testdate;

chardate = '06.2010';
date = mdy(input(substr(chardate, 2, 2), 8.), 1, input(substr(chardate, 4, 4), 8.));

date2 = input(compress('01'||chardate, "."), ddmmyy10.);

format date: mmyy10.;

run;
proc print ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: This looks more elegant than mine AND give the correct year, thx. Still, any idea why in my example the year would be one less?